# Why does partition key value need to be passed in when creating an item in a Cosmos DB container?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When creating a container in an Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL database, you configure a `partitionKeyPath` on the container, indicating which property of the items in the container will contain their partition key value. For example, using the .NET SDK:

```
Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
    id: "food",
    partitionKeyPath: "/food_group",
    throughput: 400
);
```

Then, when adding an item to the container, you must pass in a partition key value for that item:

```
Food item = new (
    id: "53634634",
    food_group: "fruit",
    name: "Apple"
);

Food createdItem = await container.CreateItemAsync<Food>(
    item: item,
    partitionKey: new PartitionKey("fruit")
);
```

**Why does the partition key value need to be passed in separately if the container is configured to know which property is to be used at the partition key?**

Comment: The SDK is probably passing the value you give in the "x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey" header: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-request-headers. I'm guessing it doesn't have the collection definition and this is the simplest way to achieve getting the value and passing it.

Comment: The code does have the collection definition though. The `CreateItemAsync<T>` method is on the Container class.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: The `partitionKey` parameter is actually optional, but providing it will avoid the overhead processing involved in extracting it from the object.**

**Explanation:**
All of the code examples I've encountered make it appear necessary to pass the `partitionKey` value into the `Container.CreateItemAsync<T>` method. Looking at the [documentation for the method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.createitemasync?view=azure-dotnet) though, it shows the parameter is optional, and says the partition key value will be extracted from the item if not provided. Furthermore, the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/72957d192772648e8a4c913443ed3233d9245c7d/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/ContainerCore.Items.cs#L65) for the `Container.CreateItemAsync<T>` method shows there is overhead involved in extracting the value of the partition key property from the object, so providing the value from the start will avoid additional processing.